# Javascript calculation not triggered inside rails nested form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I am using nested_form in my rails application. I need to add onchange event inside nested form. Each time a new row is added and value entered in the `quantity` text field, the value should gets added with `quantity` field of previously added row. The added value should display in the `total` text field. The intention is to find the sum of `quantity` and display in the `total` field. This script should work for every new row added in the nested form. Someone please help. Thanks in advance.

My `Gemfile`

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem "responders"
gem "active_model_serializers", github: "rails-api/active_model_serializers"
gem 'date_validator'
gem 'axlsx_rails'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'   
gem "select2-rails"
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha6'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.7.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.1.5'
gem "nested_form"
gem 'yaml_db'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
```

My `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require select2
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap
//= app
//= vendor
//= require_tree .
```

And my `_form.html.erb`

```
<%= nested_form_for(normalmenu_site) do |f| %>
     <%= f.text_field :total, readonly: true, class: "tot" %>
     <table class="table table-container" id="tasks">  
        <thead>
          <th>Quantity/Per Head</th>      
          <th>Action</th>    
        </thead>  
        <tbody>
          <%= f.fields_for :normal_menus ,wrapper:false  do |ff| %>
            <tr class="fields">              
            <td><%= ff.text_field :quantity, class: "dt" %></td>      
            <td><%= ff.link_to_remove "".html_safe,:class=>"fa fa-trash-o "%></td>      
            </tr>      
          <%end%>
           <%= f.link_to_add "".html_safe, :normal_menus,:class=>"fa fa-plus ", :data => { :target => "#tasks" } %>  
        </tbody>
      </table>
   <% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event){
    var field = event.field;
    var total = ($(".tot").val());
    var roleField = field.find('.dt');
    $(".dt").keyup( function() {
      alert(roleField.val());
      var total += roleField.val();
    });
  })
</script>
```

Comment: are you bearing in mind that every nested element that is added has a unique ID? have you tried `nested:fieldAdded:normal_menus` instead?

Answer (score -1):

According to the docs [here](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)

> This gem only works with Rails 3. See the rails2 branch for a plugin
>   to work in Rails 2.

`nested_form` Only works with `rails 3` but you are using `rails 5`

Comment: It works in Rails 3 and also version 4. I'm currently using in Rails 5, as well.

Comment: Still, that gem is not maintaining anymore. I could not see any new commits and the last commit is from 2013. You better use some other gem. You can go with cocoon https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon